# Write A Header To Multiple WOrkbos

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am dynamically creating an Excel workbook based off an item count - and I want to write esssentially teh same header to each workbook.  My below syntax works for the first workbook, but the second a new workbook is created the error is thrown

This is my syntax - what do I need to do so that the header row is written to each workbook that is created?

```
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True
Do While Not rs1.EOF
  i = 0
  x = 1
  name = rs1.Fields(0).Value
  Set xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
  row = 1
  xyz = 0      
  Set HeaderWrite = xlWb.Worksheets(1)      
  HeaderWrite.Cells(row, xyz + 1).Value = "Header 1"
  xyz = xyz + 1
  HeaderWrite.Cells(row, xyz + 1).Value = "Header 2"
  xyz = xyz + 1
  HeaderWrite.Cells(row, xyz + 1).Value = "Header 3"
  xyz = xyz + 1
  HeaderWrite.Cells(row, xyz + 1).Value = "Header 4"
  xyz = xyz + 1
  HeaderWrite.Cells(row, xyz + 1).Value = "Header 5"
  xyz = xyz + 1
  HeaderWrite.Cells(row, xyz + 1).Value = "Header 6"
  xyz = xyz + 1
  HeaderWrite.Cells(row, xyz + 1).Value = "Header 7"
  xyz = xyz + 1
  HeaderWrite.Cells(row, xyz + 1).Value = "Header 8"
  xyz = xyz + 1
  HeaderWrite.Cells(row, xyz + 1).Value = "Header 9"
  xyz = xyz + 1      
  xlWb.Worksheets(1).Range("$A$2") = name
  Set xlR = xlWb.Worksheets(1).Range("$N$2")
  Set rs2 = Db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM MasterDB", dbOpenDynaset)
  With rs2
     .MoveLast
     .MoveFirst
     Do While Not .EOF
        xlR.Value = .Fields(0).Value
        xlR.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Value = .Fields(2).Value
        xlR.Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Value = "Mainstreem"
        HeaderWrite.Cells(row, xyz + 1).Value = "Dept_" & i
        xyz = xyz + 1
        HeaderWrite.Cells(row, xyz + 1).Value = "Item" & i
        xyz = xyz + 1
        HeaderWrite.Cells(row, xyz + 1).Value = "CRN" & i
        xyz = xyz + 1
        i = i + 1
        Debug.Print i
        If i = 50 Then
           i = 0
           x = x + 1
           xlWb.SaveAs FileName:=sPath & sFile, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
           xlWb.Close SaveChanges:=True
           Set xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
           sFile = name & "_" & "SalesLog" & x & ".xlsx"
           xlWb.Worksheets(1).Range("$C$2") = name
           Set xlR = xlWb.Worksheets(1).Range("$Q$2")
        Else
           Set xlR = xlR.Offset(ColumnOffset:=3)
        End If
        .MoveNext
     Loop
     .Close
  End With
```

Comment: You are setting your worksheet object `HeaderWrite` outside the loop, then closing the workbook it is in within the loop (`xlWb.Close SaveChanges:=True`), so when you go to use the worksheet object again it is no longer available.

Comment: @YowE3K - ah that explains it.  But I only want to write the header info one time, if I place that inside of my loop it would write the headers each time the loop iterates.  Thoughts on avoiding that?

Comment: Without knowing where you are initially setting `xlWb` and where you are initially setting `i`, I can't be sure what the easiest solution would be.  It may be as simple as having an `If i = 0 Then` statement just inside the loop which creates the workbook, sets the `HeaderWrite` object, writes the headers and whatever other workbook initialisation is needed, and then changing your `If i = 50 Then` block to simply close the workbook and set `i = 0`.  (But that's just an "off the top of my head" suggestion.)

Comment: @YowE3K - see my edit - I think that answers your ?

Comment: The less "efficient" solution would be to replicate your header writing code just after you create the new workbook within the `If i=50 Then` block.

Comment: @YowE3K - yes duplicating the code inside the if i = 50 block would remedy - but will be pretty invasive on system resources.  If possible, I would like a "cleaner" solution

Comment: In your first file, you appear to be writing retrieved data to cells N2:P2, then Q2:S2, then T2:V2, etc.  But in your second file, you seem to be setting it up to write to Q2:S2 as the first location.  Is that deliberate?  And you write `name` to A2 in the first file, but to C2 in the second file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is completely untested, but hopefully I have moved things to the correct spots:

```
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True
Do While Not rs1.EOF
  i = 0
  x = 0  ' was 1 ??
  name = rs1.Fields(0).Value
  Set rs2 = Db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM MasterDB", dbOpenDynaset)
  With rs2
     .MoveLast
     .MoveFirst
     Do While Not .EOF
        If i = 0 Then
           Set xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
           row = 1  ' This always stays as 1 ?!?!
           xyz = 0      
           Set HeaderWrite = xlWb.Worksheets(1)      
           xyz = xyz + 1 : HeaderWrite.Cells(row, xyz).Value = "Header 1"
           xyz = xyz + 1 : HeaderWrite.Cells(row, xyz).Value = "Header 2"
           xyz = xyz + 1 : HeaderWrite.Cells(row, xyz).Value = "Header 3"
           xyz = xyz + 1 : HeaderWrite.Cells(row, xyz).Value = "Header 4"
           xyz = xyz + 1 : HeaderWrite.Cells(row, xyz).Value = "Header 5"
           xyz = xyz + 1 : HeaderWrite.Cells(row, xyz).Value = "Header 6"
           xyz = xyz + 1 : HeaderWrite.Cells(row, xyz).Value = "Header 7"
           xyz = xyz + 1 : HeaderWrite.Cells(row, xyz).Value = "Header 8"
           xyz = xyz + 1 : HeaderWrite.Cells(row, xyz).Value = "Header 9"
           If x = 0 Then
               HeaderWrite.Range("$A$2") = name
               Set xlR = HeaderWrite.Range("$N$2")
           Else
               HeaderWrite.Range("$C$2") = name
               Set xlR = HeaderWrite.Range("$Q$2")
           End If
        End If
        xlR.Value = .Fields(0).Value
        xlR.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Value = .Fields(2).Value
        xlR.Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Value = "Mainstreem"
        xyz = xyz + 1 : HeaderWrite.Cells(row, xyz).Value = "Dept_" & i
        xyz = xyz + 1 : HeaderWrite.Cells(row, xyz).Value = "Item" & i
        xyz = xyz + 1 : HeaderWrite.Cells(row, xyz).Value = "CRN" & i
        Set xlR = xlR.Offset(ColumnOffset:=3)
        i = i + 1
        Debug.Print i
        If i = 50 Then
           i = 0
           x = x + 1
           'I moved this up - otherwise I don't think you have a filename
           sFile = name & "_" & "SalesLog" & x & ".xlsx"
           xlWb.SaveAs FileName:=sPath & sFile, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
           xlWb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        End If
        .MoveNext
     Loop
     .Close
  End With
```